# acpi_osi='Windows 2015' not working

Tags: grub2, acpi

I have tried

acpi_osi='Windows 2015' in /etc/default/grub file;
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi_osi='Windows 2015'"

After update-grub an reboot machine

I ran: sudo dmesg |grep -i add

But is Missing,

ACPI: Added _OSI(Windows 2015)

Any idea, why?

Comment: Possible solution:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/539164/grub-escape-acpi-osi-windows-2015-in-grub-cmdline-linux

Answer (score 0):

solution from kernel parameters admin-guide:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=! acpi_osi=!* acpi_osi="Windows 2015""

or simply:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=! acpi_osi="Windows 2015""

Now i see in bootlog::

ACPI: Added _OSI(Windows 2015)

Thx

Comment: @Terrance
Right way; If you want to add a "Windows 2015" ( acpi_osi ), the steps are:

in the file /etc/default/grub, before GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash", write;

acpi_osi_name=Windows
edit GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT like this,
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi='${acpi_osi_name} 2015'"

update-grub

Now, if you run: sudo dmesg |grep -i added, you will get:

[    0.285056] ACPI: Added _OSI(Windows 2015)